# Check for Identical Birthdays in a Specific group size in C++

Tags: c++

I am brand new to this site. A friend told me about it and how much it has helped him, so here goes!

I am trying to create a program that will read in a certain size of a group. At this point it will then create random birthdays for each 'member' of the group (a day 1-365) and then compare to see if there were any identical birthdays in that set. The program will do this comparison for a given group size 10,000 times and keep track of how many of those trials yielded an identical birthday and return a percentage of the 10,000 trials in which there was a match.

The problem I am having is that the program will only ever return 100% and each successive run doubles that. So if a user decided to run again with a different group size, the answer then becomes '200%' then '300%' and so on.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated!

```
//This program will ask for the number of people in a group and then output
//percentage likelyhood that two birthdays occur on the same day.

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int bdays [365];
const int loop = 10000;
int identicalBday;
void setZero (int []);
int totalDoubles (int [], int);


int main()
{
    int grpSize = 1;
    cout << "This program will ask for the number of people in a group and then output \npercentage likelyhood that two birthdays occur on the same day.";
    cout << "\nHow many in group (0 quits)? ";
    cin >> grpSize;
    while (grpSize != 0)
    {
        int identicalBday = 0;
        setZero (bdays);
        cout << "In a group of " << grpSize << " the chances that two birthdays are the same is " << totalDoubles (bdays, grpSize) << "%." << endl;
        cout << "\nHow many in group (0 quits)? ";
        cin >> grpSize;
    }
    cout << "Thanks for using this program.";
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

//Sets all indicies to 0
void setZero (int bdays [])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 365; i++)
        bdays [i] = 0;
}

//Will add one to the array index associated with the random rumber
//If that index is already equal to 1, then it breaks (at least one other identical birthday exists)
//When it does break, will add one to the indenticalBday, allowing for division at the end
int totalDoubles (int bdays [], int grpSize)
{
    int tmpRand;
    for (int k = 0; k <= loop; k++)
    {   
        for (int i = 0; i <= grpSize; i++)
        {
            srand((unsigned)time(0));
            tmpRand = rand() % 365;
            if (bdays[tmpRand] == 1)
            {
                identicalBday++;
                break;
            }
            else
                bdays [tmpRand]++;
        }

    }
    return (identicalBday/loop)*100;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various errors with this code.

- As Gabe mentioned it, the `int identicalBday = 0` is local and doesn't reset the global one, which explain your 100% increase between runs. I think this error could be avoided by using a simple coding style rule: declare the variable where/when they are needed, that is the most locally possible and not at global level. For example, `identicalBday` and `bdays` should be declared inside `totalDoubles()`. Doing so will also remove all the side-effects of this function, and guarantee that everything is reset between calls.
- By recalling `srand()` at each step, you reset the seed to the same value (time doesn't change fast enough) and kill all randomness. Only call it once.
- You forget to recall `setZero(bdays)` after each `grpSize` loop.
- `(identicalBday/loop)*100;` incorrectly do an integer division and round the result to 0 (or 1 if the `srand` error is not fixed). Use float division.

Fixing those seems to give correct result here (e.g. the classic 23 gives 53%)

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback and for taking the time to check things out. Like I mentioned to Gabe, the global declaration of identicalBday messed things up along with the integer division in the last step. Everything works great now!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the line `int identicalBday = 0;` -- can you guess why?

Since you have `int` at the beginning, you are declaring a *new* variable that only exists within your `while` loop. That leaves the global `identicalBday` uninitialized, meaning that it never gets reset so it increases every time through the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your time on this. I found this error along with the integer division error this afternoon and those fixed everything!